# Does it holds that the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the support function of a convex body is minimal on balls with the same volume?

Tags: convex-analysis, lp-spaces, support-function

I was wondering if the following inequality holds.

Let $K$ be a convex body of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let us denote by $h_K$ its support function, defined as, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$$ h_K(x)={\max}\{x\cdot y\;| y\in K \}.$$

Let $B_R$ be the ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the same volume of $K$ (in  the sense of Lebesgue measure), where $R$ is its radius.

Is it true  that
$$ ||h_K ||_{L^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}\geq  ||h_{B_R}||_{L^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}(=R)?$$

Do you have some reference for this inequality? Perhaps is an easy consequence of the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequalities?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @nicomezi why should it be one?

Comment: @nicomezi But why the maximum of the support function of a convex set with fixed volume is $1$? Is there some relations? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I understood "support function" as "indicator function" (in my mothertongue it has a very different name). Now I understand, thank you.

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you! I will improve the question with the definition

Comment: Uhm, I think you mean $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{S^n})$

Comment: @AlexDoe Yes thank you!

Comment: @AlexDoe <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $R = 1$. On the way to a contradiction, suppose that $h_K(\eta) < 1$ for all $\eta \in S^{n-1}$. By compactness of $S^{n-1}$ and continuity of $h_K$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $h_K(\eta) < 1 - \epsilon$ for all $\eta \in S^{n-1}$.

Since $K$ is a convex body it may be written as the intersection of its supporting half-spaces: $K = \bigcap_{\eta \in S^{n-1}} H_\eta$ where $H_\eta = \{x : \langle x, \eta\rangle \leq h_K(\eta)\}$. Therefore $K \subset B_{1-\epsilon}$, which contradicts the assumption that $|K| = |B_1|$.